# How to trigger the interim login modal in WordPress?

Tags: wp-admin, login

I'm trying to style the native "interim login" modal form for the admin area of a theme - but I don't want to wait around for it to appear. Is there a way I can trigger it with a `$_GET` parameter?

Comment: Found the answer on [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/163299/2807). Just open up your console and run the code in the answer to trigger the modal. Pretty cool!

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, but it no longer seems to work.

Comment: Strange. It's definitely working for me; Triggering the command in the console from the admin area makes the modal pop up. I was able to break it by [disabling the hearbeat API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/heartbeat-control/), but otherwise the code works fine.

Comment: Yeah, it really seems like it should. But no dice over here.

Comment: It might have something to do with localization. I copied the whole function into the console and it worked fine.